# Find text in square brackets but not in parentheses

Tags: java, regex, wikipedia, parentheses, square-bracket

If I have a string like this (from a Wiki-markup) that I need to parse in Java:

```
this link (is [[ inParen ]] and) (this) one is [[ notInParen ]]
```

I'd like to use regex to extract the texts inside the [[ ]] but not if they are inside parentheses.  For example, in the example above it should return:

```
notInParen
```

But ignore:

```
inParen and this
```

... since they are inside parentheses.  I can find the parentheses and the brackets separately no problem:

```
.*\(.*?\).* and .*?\[\[(.*?\]\].*
```

...but can't figure out how to find the [[ ]], look around for parentheses, and ignore. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fine regex

```
\(.*?\)|\[\[(.*?)]]
```

Your desired match will be in group 1

FYI, to make it better perform you can minimize backtracking by replacing the lazy match with a negated character class.

In Java this becomes

```
String ResultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(.*?\\)|\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Note that group 1 will be empty for the cases the first part of the alternation did match.

Comment: @JeffThompson change `if(regexMatcher.find())` to `while (regexMatcher.find())` and ignore `null`s

Answer (score 4):

Does it need to be done in one go? You can do:

- Parse the string and remove all substrings contained in parentheses.
- Parse the result again and take all the desired Wikipedia links with `[[` and `]]`.

This solves the problem and makes the problem easier to solve.

After step 1 you have: `this link   one is [[ notInParen ]]`.

After step 2 you have: `notInParen`.

Comment: Ah, brilliant!  One of those "bang head against wall" with simple answer staring me in the face moments.  Would love to see the regex version, however!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way

```
String data = "this link (is [[ inParen ]] and) (this) one is [[ notInParen ]]" +
        " this link (is [[ inParen ]] and) (this) one is [[ notInParen ]]";

boolean insideParentheses = false;
int start = 0, end = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (data.charAt(i) == '(')
        insideParentheses = true;
    if (data.charAt(i) == ')')
        insideParentheses = false;
    // -> [[ and ]] inside Parentheses are not important
    if (!insideParentheses && 
            data.charAt(i) == '[' && data.charAt(i + 1) == '[') {
        start = i;
    }
    if (!insideParentheses && 
            data.charAt(i) == ']' && data.charAt(i + 1) == ']') {
        end = i;
        System.out.println(data.substring(start, end + 2));
    }
}
```

output

```
[[ notInParen ]]
[[ notInParen ]]
```